# Should application log files and user generated data files be stored in APPDATA or PROGRAMDATA

Tags: windows-7, logfiles, appdata

We are migrating our APP to Win7.  The program generates log files to help us support and also saves a number of dictionary files and settings files that are useful for the user though the user will rarely if ever actually want to interact with the files outside of our application.  They can though because they are csv files.  I built the first run through with using the APPDATA\LOCAL\OURAPPLICATION folder as the destination.  Now I am wondering if it should be PROGRAMDATA\OURAPPLICATION.

I actually think the first choice is better because it seems that everything I have scanned suggests that the PROGRAMDATA folder should be considered untouchable by the user but as I am not a programmer I am not sure.

I hope this is the right place to ask this question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key point to consider is what the scope of the data is.  If you are storing data that is associated with a specific user then you should use APPDATA and if you are storing data that is global to your program then you should use PROGRAMDATA.

Both APPDATA and PROGRAMDATA are hidden folders so the intent is for users not to be poking around in there (not that they couldn't if they wanted to).