# Do we still store program data in C:\ProgramData or in C:\Users\user1\AppData in Windows 10?

Tags: appdata, windows-10-desktop, programdata, userappdatapath

First I will explain my problem. I am updating software to fit the needs for Windows 10 users. Currently we are using `C:\ProgramData` to store Product databases and product pricing databases. Each quarter we release new version of the software that has updated product pricing databases and maybe a new and/or edited product database that the user installs. Should this data continue to be stored in ProgramData or should we switch it to store in `C:\Users\user1\AppData`?

I have been looking through questions between the difference between Program Data and AppData. [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276139/difference-between-program-data-and-appdata/27181428#27181428) 
The data for the user downloading the software isn't customized so AppData doesn't seem like the correct place but would like this to be verified.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I hope you aren't hard-coding those paths...

Comment: Difference is data shared among all users on a machine and data specific to each user.  Also, you should be using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` and similar to get these paths.

Comment: @ SLaks we are using the `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`. My question is more on coding practices to store the Product databases and product pricing databases.