# Why does my application requires admin priviliges when placed in C:\Program Files on windows 10 but not on windows 7?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse-rcp, rcp, windows-10-desktop

My Java RCP application (**App.exe**) was recently converted from **32-bit to 64-bit**. Since it is a 64-bit application i have used *NSIS* to create an installer which will dump all the required files along with *App.exe* in C:\Program Files. When the *App.exe* is run, i am getting a security exception(Access denied) when the application tries to open files (in C:\Program Files) in edit mode to dump the results/logs. When i run *App.exe* as administrator it works fine. It also works fine in windows 7 64-bit machine even when run in non-admin mode.

Any idea, as what to do to run *App.exe* in non-admin mode ?

> Note : This is not the problem of **NSIS** as samething was working fine as a 32-bit application.

Comment: As far as I know, the programs files directory was always protected. Are you sure that the win7 user isn't a admin with low UAC settings?

Comment: Ps; you might want to check %programdata%, %appdata% etc, : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276139/what-is-the-difference-between-programdata-and-appdata#27181428

Comment: @Stefan, Sorry, i missed to check the UAC setting in Windows 7. It was set to low, so set it to default and the same issue persists as in Windows 10

Comment: I am in doubt to post it as answer, although it seems a simple thing, it's also easy to overlook. I'll post it but also flag your question and let the community decide.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the programs files directory is always protected.

You should check the WIN 7 users privileges and the user's UAC settings.

*Meanwhile....*

---

You might want to reconsider where to store your data.

There is a SO post about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276139/what-is-the-difference-between-programdata-and-appdata#27181428)

> To put it straight, **ProgramData** contains application data that is not user specific.This data which will be available to all users on the computer. Any global data should be put in here.
>
> **AppData** folder contains configuration settings, downloaded information/files for a particular user. So, for example any user specific preferences and profile configurations can be stored in the AppData folder. The AppData folder is further divided into three subfolders
> **Roaming -** This folder contains data that can move with your user profile from a computer to another.
> **Local -** This folder contains data that will not move with your user profile.
> **LocalLow -** You can put in lowlevel access information such as information related to web browser running in a protected mode in this folder.

Comment: But, this is not the case with my 32-bit application. When a 32-bit application is installed in C:\Program Files, i don't see this kind of problem.
Is it something to do with the bitness ?

Comment: Stefan, Does the above comment make sense ?

Comment: Hmm, no. As far as I know program files is protected by default. But... security settings can be changed. Btw, the 32-bit folder typically is `c:\program files (x86)`