# 64- bit Eclipse RCP Application not able to read and write in Program Files or Program Files (x86)

Tags: eclipse, x86, 64-bit, eclipse-rcp, x86-64

I am trying to uplift our 32 bit Eclipse RCP application to 64 bit end state.In order to do that I have updated all the required dependencies and dlls. Also I am able to launch the application under 64 bit environment only when the application is kept anywhere outside Program Files or Program Files(x86). When it is installed in the said location it could not be launched , a result view could not be created because it tries to write a search file in the place where it is been installed.

But the main problem is the same set of code works for 32 bit version no matter where it is installed. Also the 32 bit version of application can read or write result to any desired location without being launched as admin. 
And the 64 bit version of the application does the same when launched as admin.

**In order to find out more I tried with eclipse_mars_x86 and eclipse_mars_x86_64 with different location.When the workspace is inside Program Files or Program Files(x86) 32 bit of eclipse can access it without being launched as admin but the same can not be done through 64 bit of eclipse, without launching it as admin.**

Any idea why eclipse behave this way , and can this be a reason for my issue ? Also if there is any solution to this ?

Also see the error log for more information.

```
    !SESSION 2018-06-04 13:13:23.774 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_172
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -host 
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consolelog -host 

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-06-04 13:13:43.383

    !MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle results-view (108).
    !STACK 0
    org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in __.resultsview.Activator.start() of bundle results-view.
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.PropertyTesterDescriptor.instantiate(PropertyTesterDescriptor.java:92)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtension.findTypeExtender(TypeExtension.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtension.findTypeExtender(TypeExtension.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtension.findTypeExtender(TypeExtension.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtension.findTypeExtender(TypeExtension.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtension.findTypeExtender(TypeExtension.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtension.findTypeExtender(TypeExtension.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtensionManager.getProperty(TypeExtensionManager.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TestExpression.evaluate(TestExpression.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.WithExpression.evaluate(WithExpression.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationResultCache.evaluate(EvaluationResultCache.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.ExpressionAuthority.evaluate(ExpressionAuthority.java:165)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationAuthority.refsWithSameExpression(EvaluationAuthority.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationAuthority.sourceChanged(EvaluationAuthority.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.ExpressionAuthority.sourceChanged(ExpressionAuthority.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.ExpressionAuthority.sourceChanged(ExpressionAuthority.java:290)
        at org.eclipse.ui.AbstractSourceProvider.fireSourceChanged(AbstractSourceProvider.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.checkActivePart(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:401)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.checkActivePart(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:300)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.handleCheck(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:286)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.checkOtherSources(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:855)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider$6.handleEvent(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:839)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1262)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1052)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_ACTIVATE(Decorations.java:1647)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_ACTIVATE(Shell.java:2137)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4525)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1610)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2061)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.BringWindowToTop(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.bringToTop(Decorations.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.open(Shell.java:1217)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:797)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.open(WorkbenchWindow.java:818)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$70.runWithException(Workbench.java:3719)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
        at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1595)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4683)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading.runWithoutExceptions(StartupThreading.java:94)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.init(Workbench.java:1590)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2623)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
        at com.__.Application.start(Application.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\product-18.05.31-SNAPSHOT\__\Results\search.xml (Access is denied)
        at com.__.results.XmlWriter.writeXML(XmlWriter.java:97)
        at com.__.results.SummaryParser.writeXML(SummaryParser.java:50)
        at com.__.views.ResultsDisplayer.initializeModel(ResultsDisplayer.java:322)
        at com__.views.ResultsDisplayer.initializeCache(ResultsDisplayer.java:249)
        at com.__.resultsview.Activator.start(Activator.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        ... 94 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\product-18.05.31-SNAPSHOT\__\Results\search.xml (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
        at com.__.results.XmlWriter.writeXML(XmlWriter.java:87)
        ... 101 more
    Root exception:
    java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\product-18.05.31-SNAPSHOT\__\Results\search.xml (Access is denied)
        at com.__.results.XmlWriter.writeXML(XmlWriter.java:97)
        at com.__.SummaryParser.writeXML(SummaryParser.java:50)
        at com.__.views.ResultsDisplayer.initializeModel(ResultsDisplayer.java:322)
        at com.__.views.ResultsDisplayer.initializeCache(ResultsDisplayer.java:249)
        at com.__.resultsview.Activator.start(Activator.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.PropertyTesterDescriptor.instantiate(PropertyTesterDescriptor.java:92)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtension.findTypeExtender(TypeExtension.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtension.findTypeExtender(TypeExtension.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtension.findTypeExtender(TypeExtension.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtension.findTypeExtender(TypeExtension.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtension.findTypeExtender(TypeExtension.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtension.findTypeExtender(TypeExtension.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtensionManager.getProperty(TypeExtensionManager.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TestExpression.evaluate(TestExpression.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.WithExpression.evaluate(WithExpression.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationResultCache.evaluate(EvaluationResultCache.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.ExpressionAuthority.evaluate(ExpressionAuthority.java:165)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationAuthority.refsWithSameExpression(EvaluationAuthority.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationAuthority.sourceChanged(EvaluationAuthority.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.ExpressionAuthority.sourceChanged(ExpressionAuthority.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.ExpressionAuthority.sourceChanged(ExpressionAuthority.java:290)
        at org.eclipse.ui.AbstractSourceProvider.fireSourceChanged(AbstractSourceProvider.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.checkActivePart(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:401)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.checkActivePart(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:300)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.handleCheck(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:286)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.checkOtherSources(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:855)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider$6.handleEvent(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:839)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1262)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1052)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_ACTIVATE(Decorations.java:1647)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_ACTIVATE(Shell.java:2137)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4525)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1610)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2061)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.BringWindowToTop(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.bringToTop(Decorations.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.open(Shell.java:1217)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:797)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.open(WorkbenchWindow.java:818)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$70.runWithException(Workbench.java:3719)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
        at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1595)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4683)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading.runWithoutExceptions(StartupThreading.java:94)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.init(Workbench.java:1590)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2623)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
        at com.__.Application.start(Application.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\product-18.05.31-SNAPSHOT\__\Results\search.xml (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
        at com.__.results.XmlWriter.writeXML(XmlWriter.java:87)
        ... 101 more
```

Comment: Looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50758075/2670892) question.

Comment: @greg-449 I also think the same but I want to clear my understanding regarding eclipse. Is this something related to eclipse ? Because at the end all RCP applications are basically eclipse product