# BDE session files gets vanished from Temp folder

Tags: delphi, windows-10

i am using Delphi-5(old) application with InterBase database, I have assigned the BDE session file during runtime to Temp\XYZ folder.

When the application is left ideal for some time suddenly the XYZ folder in TEMP folder gets deleted by itself.

The Customers complaining about this issue are in  Windows 10 Enterprise, 64 bit.

I am aware that Microsft has got a new option "Storage Sense" in windows 10 which will automatically clear the TEMP folder.

when the application is in use the session files handle will be opened the application even though it is opened it is getting deleted automatically...  (Have tried to delete the temp folder manually unable to delete it when the app is in use.)

Can someone please suggest me ideas on this?

Comment: Windows 10 has a _Delete temporary files that my apps aren't using_ option you need to make sure it's not checked. open Start > Settings > System > Storage > 
Toggle on Storage sense >Click Change how we free up space

Comment: Thanks, @Sami !! will it deletes the files even if it been accessed by a process (Which is ideal for 15 mins) minimized.

Comment: Any help on this is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple - don't use the TEMP folder. Use something like:

- `%APPDATA%`
- `%LOCALAPPDATA%`
- `%PROGRAMDATA%`

For more information:
[What is the difference between ProgramData and AppData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276139/what-is-the-difference-between-programdata-and-appdata)